# How can one print the name of an identifier or binding in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, code-inspection

Supose I want to print the name and the value of a "variable" in Haskell. The name is known at compile time! Is there a better way than in the following example?

```
module V
(e, c, eV, h, hbar, nm, k, viewAllConstants) where
import Text.Printf
c = 2.99792458e8::Double
e = exp(1)
eV = 1.602176565e-19
h = 6.62606957e-34
hbar = h/(2*pi)
nm = 1e-9
k = 1.3806488e-23
viewAllConstants = do
    putStr ((\a b -> (foldl (++) "" ( zipWith (++) a (map (printf " = %.2e\n") b))))
        ["c", "e", "eV", "h", "hbar", "nm", "k"]
        [c, e, eV, h, hbar, nm, k] )
```

Please post a working code example (runhaskell) in your answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of python eval in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469139/equivalent-of-python-eval-in-haskell)

Comment: In Lisp, the distinction between data and code is blurred and everything is inspectable and dynamic at runtime. In Haskell, all types and binding names are erased at compile time, which allows for a huge amount of optimisation.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you want this? Depending on exactly what you're after, Template Haskell may or may not be able to help.

Comment: @ MathematicalOrchid I think the question right now, reflects better what I want to do: print the name of a binding/identifier not the value. The name is known at compile time!

Comment: @PeterHall This seems to answer my question. Still strange, that there are no source inspection/debugging options. In ghci I have the command ":bindings", which lists all bindings. For debbugging this is very useful.

Comment: @PeterHall: A Lisp function only receives references to the values of its arguments.  It doesn't know any more than a Haskell function does what identifiers the caller bound those values to (if any!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it! You just can't do it like you're thinking. Some language implementations use dictionaries to represent the environments in which expressions are evaluated. Some of the more foolish ones expose this mechanism to programmers. This is foolish because it prevents the implementors from switching to faster techniques in the future. Haskell does not do anything like that, except maybe in the type checker. But that doesn't stop you from building and using such dictionaries yourself!

If you're dealing with a bunch of things of the same type, you're in luck—you can use a `Map` or a trie to connect names with values. If you need things of various types, your life gets more complicated—see [HList records](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-HList-Record.html) for example.

All that said, I think you should think carefully about how much you really want this. It's kind of unusual.

Answer (score 3):

As @PeterHall said:

> In Lisp, the distinction between data and code is blurred and everything is inspectable and dynamic at runtime. In Haskell, **all types and binding names are erased at compile time**, which allows for a huge amount of optimisation.

In other words, *the name is **not** known at runtime.*

Furthermore, these are not *'variables'*, these are *constants*, or, as said before, *bindings*. For this reason, there is no point in being able to access the name of the binding, because it will never change.

As @MathematicalOrchid suggested, there may be a template Haskell solution, though it may be only relatively useful.

As for a better way of printing the bindings, try this:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

viewAllConstants = forM_ (\(a, b) -> putStrLn (a ++ " = " ++ show b)) 
                   $ zip ["c", "e", "eV", "h", "hbar", "nm", "k"] 
                         [ c,   e,   eV,   h,   hbar,   nm,   k ]
```

Comment: Of course the name is known at compile time... I think you meant to say something else but I'm not quite sure what.

Comment: @ReidBarton Whoops, it's *run*time! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a bit confused about what you really want. The name of the identifier `c` is just `"c"`; there's no problem in printing that.

I assume what you really want is to eliminate the duplication in your module between `["c", "e", "eV", "h", "hbar", "nm", "k"]` and `[c,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k]`. How, concretely, do you intend to do that? Then we can talk about whether it can or cannot work in Haskell.

Probably it will come down to one or both of

1. Lack of `eval`. If you keep the list `["c", "e", "eV", "h", "hbar", "nm", "k"]`, you could hope to evaluate those strings to find out the values of the corresponding variables. While you could potentially embed a Haskell interpreter in your program, there is not necessarily any mapping at runtime of the names `"c"`, `"e"`, ... to their values, as has been pointed out by others, so you just cannot go from the string `"c"` to the value `2.99792458e8`.
2. Referential transparency. You could keep the list `[c,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k]` and hope for some magic way to recover the strings `"c"`, `"e"`, ... from it. But that is also impossible. `[c,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k]` is just a list of Doubles and, since `c = 2.99792458e8`, we also have `[c,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k] = [2.99792458e8,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k]`, and there is no way to extract `"c"` from the latter.

Answer (score 2):

> Supose I want to print the name and the value of a "variable" in Haskell. The name is known at compile time!

The name is known **in some scopes**, and not in others.  This is critical.  Let's look at your example code:

```
module V (e, c, eV, h, hbar, nm, k, viewAllConstants) where

c = 2.99792458e8
e = exp(1)
eV = 1.602176565e-19
h = 6.62606957e-34
hbar = h/(2*pi)
nm = 1e-9
k = 1.3806488e-23

viewAllConstants = do
    putStr (foldl (++) "" (map ("\n" ++)
                    ( zipWith (++) ["c", "e", "eV", "h", "hbar", "nm", "k"]
                        (map ((" = " ++) . show) [c,e,eV,h,hbar,nm,k])
                    )

                )
        )
```

`putStr`, `foldl`, `map`, `zipWith` and `show` are functions defined in modules that come with GHC, and are compiled separately from your program.  These functions have no way of knowing the names of your variables—all they get handed is their values.

Note that contrary to Peter Hall's comment, this isn't a Haskell vs. Lisp difference.  In Lisp, the arguments to a procedure are passed by reference to the value, not to the symbol; a Lisp function doesn't any more know the names of its arguments than a Haskell one does.

Also, you can pass arbitrary expressions as arguments to functions in both languages.  These are values that aren't bound to variables in the call site.