# Command line Haskell: Running function from main.hs

Tags: haskell, io

My program is made up of three parts: Machine, Interpreter, and Compiler.

It doesn't really matter what each one does, I'm sure you could guess though. What matters is that there is a function in Compiler.hs that returns a list of *Instr* (which is a data type I defined in Machine). This function is called **ccomp**, which takes a *Com* type as input (a data type I defined in Interpreter).

```
ccomp :: Com -> [Instr]

ccomp (Assign v x) = acomp(x) ++ [STORE v]
ccomp (Seq c1 c2) = ccomp (c1) ++ ccomp (c2)
```

My next task is to write a main function that allows the **ccomp** function to be run from the command line using `stack exec project-exe "Assign \"x \" (Plus (N 5) (N 3))"`

The code above runs the main.hs file with the String between quotes as an argument. The problem is I can't figure out what to put in the main function:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Compiler

main :: IO ()
main = do
       args <- getArgs
       putStrLn (ccomp(head(args)))
```

This doesn't work, the expected type for **ccomp** is *Interpreter.Com* and it receives a *String*. I've tried changing the type using **read**, but that didn't work as the *Com* constructor was not in scope.

Is there a simple way of passing the command line argument into the **ccomp** function that I'm missing?

Comment: “I've tried changing the type using `read`” – ok, sounds sensible; “but that didn't work as the Com constructor was not in scope” –  that's a quite different problem from what this question here is about, and should be asked in a different, suitably self-contained question.

Comment: thanks, @leftaroundabout, I was just wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish this task without having to change the type from String to Com. When I run the ccomp function from the GHCI interface it automatically interprets the argument as the correct data type, would it be possible to somehow simulate this from inside the haskell script main.hs? (for example I can run ccomp (Assign (V "x") (N 5)), after compiling Compiler.hs)I hope this makes sense, let me know if I can clear anything up

Comment: No. This would in general require something [`eval`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)-like, which Haskell emphatically doesn't have. (_[Well...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469139/equivalent-of-python-eval-in-haskell)_)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked the links but unfortunately, the task requires me to not import any packages apart from the compiler itself and System.Environement. So you are saying what I'm trying to achieve is impossible without either importing a package or directly converting a String into a list of Coms?  Do you think there could be an out-of-the-box solution to this problem? Or am I stuck with having to convert the user input from a String into the correct type? @leftaroundabout

Comment: I'm saying that what you're trying to do is the wrong thing to start with. You should either _parse_ a pure data input (for which `Read` provides a primitive, but usable mechanism), or you shouldn't have an executable at all and just work in the REPL.

Comment: for `read` to work, you probably need to `import Interpreter` as well, in your `Main` module. surely you are allowed to do that. your `Com` data type should have `deriving Read`.